# Google Drive API - Receive notification from approval workflow

Tags: google-drive-api

I published a webhook notification to next URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileID/watch

I receive some notifications (very poor), but when user approve a file I not sent API notification:

[image: Approval option]

Its is possible receive a notification when users approve/reject file?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible at the moment. There is a Feature Request to include Approvals to the API here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208025958, if this doesn't apply to your use case you could create a new FR using this template https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106